Get url of file blob in Azure Blobstorage through Dapr
I have a solution with a .NET 8 API that communicates with Azure Blob storage through Dapr sidecar.
With a BindingRequest im able to retrieve the blob contents, but i also need to retrieve the public url for that file blob. I cannot find any documentation on how to get the "azure metadata" for the file, and the BindingResponse doesn't provide any clues.
Any tips on how to get the public url for a file blob in Azure through Dapr?
var request = new BindingRequest("blobbinding", "get");

request.Metadata.Add("fileName", name);

var response = await _daprClient.InvokeBindingAsync(request);

// response.Data contains the filecontents

